# Why does my file get overwritten?

Tags: python, file-io

When using this code in python:

```
 f = open('ping.log', 'r+')
 f.write("["+time.ctime()+"]"+"Status")
 f.close()
```

My file always gets overwritten. And only has one line in it, like this:

> [Fri Sep 02 16:30:56 2011]Status

Why is it getting overwritten?

Comment: Is what you're trying to say something like:
"I am using Python 2.7 on Windows XP.
I do two file writes:
{CODE SAMPLE}
Why is the file only showing the first write, but not the second?"

Because that code sample's important.

Comment: Code:    f = open('ping.log', 'r+')
   f.write("["+time.ctime()+"]"+"Status")
   f.close()

Comment: File: [Fri Sep 02 16:30:56 2011]Status

Comment: You remember to tell `f` you want to _append_ to its current contents?

Comment: I want to file saves all times write

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing because you are effectively recreating the file each time as you are overwriting the first N bytes every time. If you wrote less bytes you'd see the "old" information still there.

You need to open the file for "append"

> 'a' opens the file for appending

[Source](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Not recreating, it just overwrites the first N bytes. It'd be visible if there was more content inside it.

Answer (score 2):

`r+` sets the initial file pointer to the beginning. Either seek to the end or use `a` mode.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python). Open the file with the "a" mode:

```
f = open("ping.log","a")
...
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
>   argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
>   way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will
>   only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
>   name will be erased), **and 'a' opens the file for appending;** any data
>   written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
>   file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
>   will be assumed if it’s omitted.

so use

```
f = open('ping.log', 'a')
f.write("["+time.ctime()+"]"+"Status")
f.close()
```